# How to extract multiple elements from specific positions in an ND array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have two ND array (10*4*4*2*4), where I look for the maximum values per column in the first and want to extract the element in the same position from the second.

To make things simple, let's assume I have A and B as follow:

```
A = randi(100,4,3,2);
B = randi(10,size(A));
```

Now, I look for the indices of the maximum element with:

```
[~,ind] = max(A);
```

And then I want to use `ind` to extract the elements from `B`. The optimal option would be something like `C = B(ind)`, but that clearly doesn't work. Matlab refers to `ind` as linear indexing just like I would write `C = B(ind(:))`, except the the size of `C` becomes like `ind` (i.e. 1*3*2).

So I tried also something like this (that I found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/32362-how-to-extract-elements-along-specified-dimension-of-array)):

```
m = {ind,':',':'};
C = B(m{:})
```

But this results in an array of size 6*3*2, where `ind` is the linear indexing of each column in `B`. Off course I can use a loop to do that, but I'm quite sure there is a more efficient and elegant way.

**Example:**

```
A(:,:,1) =
    40    89    30
    73    77    30
    59    61    14
    29     2    30
A(:,:,2) =
    82    79     5
     3    40    62
    46    76    42
    22    52    74

B(:,:,1) =
     5     1     9
     3     3     5
     8     4     4
     8     3     9
B(:,:,2) =
     1     4     3
     5     4     8
    10     8     5
     9     1     3

ind(:,:,1) =
     2     1     1
ind(:,:,2) =
     1     1     4
```

So the result should be:

```
C =
     3     1
     1     4
     9     3
```

Note that I look for a general solution, and not one that fits only the dimensions in this example.

Comment: What's the desired size (shape) of `C` in your example?

Comment: `C` should look like `squeeze(ind)`.

Comment: Great, that's what my solution does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **three dimensions**, you can use [`sub2ind`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert from (sub)indices to linear indices:

```
[~, ind] = max(A,[],1);
linind = sub2ind(size(A), reshape(ind, size(A,2), size(A,3)), ...
    repmat((1:size(A,2)).', 1, size(A,3)), ...
    repmat(1:size(A,3), size(A,2), 1));
C = B(linind);
```

---

For an **arbitrary number of dimensions**, it's easier to collapse all dimensions beyond the first into one before calling `max`. This also makes it easier to replace `sub2ind` by a faster, manual computation:

```
Ar = reshape(A, size(A,1), []); % collapse all dimensions beyond the first
[~, ind] = max(Ar,[],1); % arg max of each column
linind = ind + (0:size(Ar,2)-1)*size(Ar,1); % convert to linear indices
C = B(linind); % index into C
sz = size(A); % size of A
C = reshape(C, sz(2:end)); % reshape C according to shape of A
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you generalize this to my original problem (size of 10*4*4*2*4)? Would I just have to add `repmats` for each dimension?

Comment: Thanks a million! It works like a charm ;) and even more important - I can understand this... I will +1 this as soon as I have more free votes (I ran out of them today)